# Retorno do pagseguro parou de ser recebido repentinamente

Tags: php

Estou com um problema em um site que fiz a pouco tempo, nos primeiros dias, quando um cliente realizava um pagamento no PagSeguro eu recebia o retorno normalmente com as atualizações do status da compra, porém, cerca de duas semanas atrás parei de receber esse retorno repentinamente. Revirei meu código diversas vezes atrás de um possível erro, pesquisei de varias formas no Google, cheguei até mesmo a desabilitar o `mod_security` no servidor como alguns sites sugeriram e nada...

Código do arquivo de retorno

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
require('../../PagSeguroLibrary/PagSeguroLibrary.php');

/* Tipo de notificação recebida */
$type = $_REQUEST['notificationType'];
LogPagSeguro::info("Uma Notificação do tipo '{$type}' chegou!");
/*
* Código da notificação recebida
* https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/api-de-notificacoes.html
*/
$code = $_REQUEST['notificationCode'];
/* Verificando tipo de notificação recebida */
if ($type == 'transaction') {
LogPagSeguro::info('Nova notificação retornada do PagSeguro');
$credencial = PagSeguroConfig::getAccountCredentials();
/* Obtendo o objeto PagSeguroTransaction a partir do código de notificação */
$transaction = PagSeguroNotificationService::checkTransaction(
    $credencial,
    $code
);
/* código do status da transação */
$status = (int) $transaction->getStatus()->getValue();
$requestId = (int) $transaction->getReference();
$statusNome = $transaction->getStatus()->getTypeFromValue();

if($status && $requestId){
    /*atualiza o status da compra

      Código adicional

      grava no log do pagseguro
    */
    if($qrUpdateInfo->affected_rows == 1) LogPagSeguro::info('Pedido "'.$requestId.'" atualizado com sucesso!');
    else LogPagSeguro::warning("Ocorreu um erro na atualização do status do pedido         '{$requestId}'! mysqli_errno({$qrUpdateInfo->errno})");
}
}else{
    LogPagSeguro::warning("Uma Notificação do tipo '{$type}' foi recusada!");
}
```

**Estou usando `$_REQUEST` pois estranhamente ele não recebia os `$_POST`s do PagSeguro**.
Até aí nenhum mistério, acredito eu.

Porém no momento que faço a compra, ele me manda o retorno daquela compra e grava no arquivo de log normalmente, mas as atualizações do status da compra não estão chegando mais...

Log:

```
{2014/05/19 13:41:32} [Info] PagSeguroPaymentService.Register(PagSeguroPaymentRequest: array (
  'Reference' => 79,
  'SenderEmail' => 'null',
)) - begin 
{2014/05/19 13:41:33} [Info] PagSeguroPaymentService.Register(PagSeguroPaymentRequest: array (
  'Reference' => 79,
  'SenderEmail' => 'null',
)) - end {1}13DC46D97171BB4444F60F81E8A4A98C 
{2014/05/19 13:56:36} [Info] PagSeguroPaymentService.Register(PagSeguroPaymentRequest: array (
  'Reference' => 80,
  'SenderEmail' => 'null',
)) - begin 
{2014/05/19 13:56:38} [Info] PagSeguroPaymentService.Register(PagSeguroPaymentRequest: array (
  'Reference' => 80,
  'SenderEmail' => 'null',
)) - end {1}E0E95A81EAEA5B2AA4C66F9C8806485E 
{2014/05/19 14:28:02} [Info] PagSeguroPaymentService.Register(PagSeguroPaymentRequest: array (
  'Reference' => 84,
  'SenderEmail' => 'null',
)) - begin 
{2014/05/19 14:28:04} [Info] PagSeguroPaymentService.Register(PagSeguroPaymentRequest: array (
  'Reference' => 84,
  'SenderEmail' => 'null',
)) - end {1}A864EE379C9C8FFCC4A48FBACABECBC3 
{2014/05/19 14:30:57} [Info] PagSeguroPaymentService.Register(PagSeguroPaymentRequest: array (
  'Reference' => 85,
  'SenderEmail' => 'null',
)) - begin 
{2014/05/19 14:30:59} [Info] PagSeguroPaymentService.Register(PagSeguroPaymentRequest: array (
  'Reference' => 85,
  'SenderEmail' => 'null',
)) - end {1}53AD3EF23F3F89A884559FBFBD464A36 
{2014/05/19 14:56:27} [Info] PagSeguroPaymentService.Register(PagSeguroPaymentRequest: array (
  'Reference' => 86,
  'SenderEmail' => 'null',
)) - begin 
{2014/05/19 14:56:28} [Info] PagSeguroPaymentService.Register(PagSeguroPaymentRequest: array (
  'Reference' => 86,
  'SenderEmail' => 'null',
)) - end {1}ABC65A77767683A774117FA5386D3C90 
{2014/05/19 14:59:10} [Info] PagSeguroPaymentService.Register(PagSeguroPaymentRequest: array (
  'Reference' => 87,
  'SenderEmail' => 'null',
)) - begin 
{2014/05/19 14:59:11} [Info] PagSeguroPaymentService.Register(PagSeguroPaymentRequest: array (
  'Reference' => 87,
  'SenderEmail' => 'null',
)) - end {1}27E7C9EE7F7F95E334BFDF9131FBDA3E 
{2014/05/19 15:16:17} [Info] PagSeguroPaymentService.Register(PagSeguroPaymentRequest: array (
  'Reference' => 88,
  'SenderEmail' => 'null',
)) - begin 
{2014/05/19 15:16:19} [Info] PagSeguroPaymentService.Register(PagSeguroPaymentRequest: array (
  'Reference' => 88,
  'SenderEmail' => 'null',
)) - end {1}D4E7C61FADAD6FF99403AFB16E1D0930
```

**Outra dúvida, o firewall do servidor poderia estar bloqueando o retorno do PagSeguro?**

Eu sinceramente já perdi as esperanças com o PagSeguro, mas já que não posso migrar esse cliente para o Moip tenho que dar um jeito de resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei o problema, e mais algumas recomendações...

- 1 - Não basta setar no pagseguro a url de retorno, no momento que você manda para o pagseguro a compra você deve setar a url de retorno tambem

  > $pagSeguro->setNotificationURL('`http://seudominio/arquivoderetorno`');
- 2 - Libere os ips no seu firewall

  ```
  186.234.16.8
  186.234.16.9
  186.234.48.8
  186.234.48.9
  200.147.112.136
  200.147.112.137
  ```
- 3 - Desabilite seu mod_security

Fontes: 
[IMasters](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/295416-retorno-automatico-pagseguro/)
[Blog pag seguro](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/atendimento/perguntas_frequentes/nao-recebi-o-post-com-retorno-automatico-o-que-devo-fazer.jhtml#rmcl)

Comment: mas pelo que tinha entendido, seu código funcionava e derrepente parou. se vc não setou o retorno então ele nunca funcionou...bom o mais importante é ter corrigido. abraços

Comment: @Dorathoto mas é isso que aconteceu, eu recebia o retorno mesmo sem ter setado o retorno junto ao envio, até por que não fazia ideia de que isso era necessário, por isso foi tão difícil de arrumar dessa vez...

Answer (score 1):

Não analisei seu código, mas como não tinha respostas vou dar 2 caminhos que irá ajuda-lo a quem sabe solucionar;

1º - verifique se no pagseguro, na conta que esta utilizando para pagar, não desabilitou a página de retorno, se desabilitou por algum engano, ele não vai enviar nada para você.

2º - Faz um teste, essa página que recebe o retorno, faz ela criar um arquivo .txt caso ela seja acessada, faz uma compra de teste, e verifique se ela criou o arquivo. se ela não criar o arquivo por algum motivo ela não esta sendo executada.

Comment: ja verifiquei o retorno e está ativo, vou fazer o segundo teste agora

Comment: testei da segunda maneira e o arquivo nao foi acessado pelo pagseguro